V4L2 on Raspberry Pi: Forward captured image to ISP without copying?
I'm trying to learn how to use V4L2 to capture an image and then process it using the ISP module of the Raspberry Pi.
Here is my idea:

Capture a RAW 10-bit image using the Unicam capture device (in my case /dev/video0)
Pass the image to the Video output interface of the ISP device (in my case /dev/video13)
Get a decoded image from the Capture interface of the ISP device (in my case /dev/video14)

Is it possible to do step 2 without copying the captured image?
